# Returning a boolean value in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I am doing a client side form validation to check if passwords match. But the validation function always returns `undefined`.

```
function validatePassword(errorMessage)
{
   var password = document.getElementById("password");
   var confirm_password = document.getElementById("password_confirm");

   if(password.value)
   {
      // Check if confirm_password matches
      if(password.value != confirm_password.value)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // If password is empty but confirm password is not
      if(confirm_password.value)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Please note that the `validatePassword` is called from a member function of the Form object.

```
function Form(validation_fn)
{
   // Do other stuff
   this.submit_btn = document.getElementById("submit");
   this.validation_fn = validation_fn;
}

Form.prototype.submit = funciton()
{
   var result;
   if(this.validation_fn)
   {
      result = this.validation_fn();
   }

   //result is always undefined
   if(result)
   {
       //do other stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: This function will never return `undefined`. Please define *"is called from a member function of the Form object."*

Comment: just hit CTRL+SHIFT+J -- check if error If yes post here , If not  then open debugger and run it .

Comment: @AnilShanbhag Does not return any error. I did open the debugger and when I step through the code, is when I realised that result is being set as `undefined`

Comment: You're excluding some relevant information from your question. I would guess either that somewhere in there you're making a server request (or doing some other asynchronous action), or when you create the `new Form()` object, you're either not passing a function, or you're trying to pass one that doesn't yet exist. Have you verified that `validatePassword` is even being invoked? Please provide all relevant code. There's nothing here that demonstrates an issue.

Comment: `validatePassword` is being invoked because I can put a break point there and it hits it. There is really not much to put in there.. The only suspicious thing is that in Form Class, this.validation_fn holds the function ptr to validatePassword right? So does the return value get lost when validatePassword returns? does not make sense but still I may missing something..

Comment: ok I found it.. When I created a new Form Object, it should've been

new Form(function() {return eval(objs.validator);})

instead of 

new Form(function() {eval(objs.validator);}),, missed a return statement in there.. Thanks guys for helping

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could simplify this a lot:

- Check whether one is not empty
- Check whether they are equal

This will result in this, which will always return a boolean. Your function also should always return a boolean, but you can see it does a little better if you simplify your code:

```
function validatePassword()
{
   var password = document.getElementById("password");
   var confirm_password = document.getElementById("password_confirm");

   return password.value !== "" && password.value === confirm_password.value;
       //       not empty       and              equal
}
```

Comment: @primvdb That still returns `undedined`.. I am doing something bizzare

Comment: @tryurbest: Are you getting any errors perhaps? This function *always* returns, and what it returns is a boolean... And in your code, then `this.validation_fn` should be false. What is the value of `this.validation_fn`?

Comment: @pimvdb.. AS you can see I am assigning the value of `this.validation_fn` to `result` right.. When I step via the debugger, result is undefined.

Comment: @tryurbest: You're only doing so `if(this.validation_fn)`. So perhaps *that* variable is `undefined` somehow. Just check to make sure.

Comment: @primvdb that is just to check if there is a validation_fn or not in the Form object.. If there is, call the function with result = this.validation()

Comment: If the function `this.validation_fn` exists, then `result` will always be a boolean. Currently it isn't, so the function `this.validation_fn` probably does not exist. Are you really sure it does exist on the Form object?

Comment: @primvdb It does because when I put a breakpoint in validatePassword which is in a different file, it does hit it and I can step through and reach the return function as well.. When the stack pointer goes back in the form object, the result is still undefined.. So there is something being lost in between..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4272/discussion-between-tryurbest-and-pimvdb)

Answer (score 8):

You could wrap your return value in the Boolean function

```
Boolean([return value])
```

That'll ensure all falsey values are false and truthy statements are true.

Comment: btw u can also try `return !!somevalue`

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to use var/let while declaring any variable.See below examples for JS compiler behaviour.

```
function  func(){
return true;
}

isBool = func();
console.log(typeof (isBool));   // output - string


let isBool = func();
console.log(typeof (isBool));   // output - boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

An old thread, sure, but a popular one apparently. It's 2020 now and none of these answers have addressed the issue of unreadable code. @pimvdb's answer takes up less lines, but it's also pretty complicated to follow. For easier debugging and better readability, I should suggest refactoring the OP's code to something like this, and adopting an early return pattern, as this is likely the main reason you were unsure of why the were getting undefined:

```
function validatePassword() {
   const password = document.getElementById("password");
   const confirm_password = document.getElementById("password_confirm");

   if (password.value.length === 0) {
      return false;
   }

   if (password.value !== confirm_password.value) {
      return false;
   }
  
   return true;
}
```

Comment: If the functions only purpose is to return a boolean then the function name should conform to a naming conventions such as `isValidPassword`

Answer (score 0):

If we don't return anything explicitly, Javascript functions implicitly returns 'undefined'.
In the below code, one condition is not returning anything, which is causing it to return undefined. I have mentioned this in the code comments.

```
function validatePassword(errorMessage)
{
   var password = document.getElementById("password");
   var confirm_password = document.getElementById("password_confirm");

   if(password.value)
   {
      // Check if confirm_password matches
      if(password.value != confirm_password.value)
      {
         return false;
      }
     //Here a return statement is missing
   }
   else
   {
      
      if(confirm_password.value)
      {
         return false;
      }
  // Here a return statement is missing
   }
   return true;
}
```